# Cypress binary is missing error in the Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, cypress, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to the Azure devOps pipeline and am having some issue running cypress project in the pipeline. The issue is `The cypress npm package is installed, but the Cypress binary is missing.`

This is what my yml files looks like.

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: ${{ parameters.node_version }}
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: yarn | $(Agent.OS) | yarn.lock
      path: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)
      restoreKeys: |
        yarn | "$(Agent.OS)"
    displayName: Cache Yarn packages
  - bash: |
      yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
    displayName: 'Yarn Install'
  - bash: >-
      yarn cypress run 
      --browser ${{ parameters.browser }} --headless
      --spec "$(spec)"
      --env configFile=$(locale),grep=$(grep),grepTags=$(grepTags),storeType=$(storeType),storeId=$(storeId)
    displayName: "Cypress Run $(specName)"
    env:
      TERM: xterm
  - bash: >-
      yarn cypress:merge
    displayName: "Merge Cypress test results"
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    env:
      TERM: xterm
```

But the CI results in below error,
[image]